# How to do query to locate specific text in string and grab section next to it?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Trying to understand LEFT and LOCATE with mysql to help me process a string

I have text that contains a bunch of data and within it is

street_num="9716", street_name=

I need to extract just the street num

so I was trying to do

```
SELECT LEFT( newdata, LOCATE( 'street_name=', 'newdata' ) ) 
FROM `uploadTracker` 
WHERE `type` =0
```

in that example I would like it to return 9716

Comment: Sounds like bad database design. If you cant change that i would just grab the whole cell and do the manipulation in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) becomes very handy

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(newdata, 'street_num="', -1), '"', 1) street_num
  FROM uploadTracker
 WHERE type = 0
```

Output:

```
| STREET_NUM |
|------------|
|       9716 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c489b/5)** demo